# How can I access event variable outside of JSX component React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, youtube-api

I have a YouTube JSX component in my file.
All my imports are here:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import YouTube, { YouTubeProps } from "react-youtube";
```

```
<YouTube
                    videoId={"di0MtYgeJNE"} // defaults -> ''
                    //id={string} // defaults -> ''
                    //className={string} // defaults -> ''
                    //iframeClassName={string} // defaults -> ''
                    //style={object} // defaults -> {}
                    //title={string} // defaults -> ''
                    //loading={string} // defaults -> undefined
                    //opts={obj} // defaults -> {}
                    //onReady={ready} // defaults -> noop
                    onPlay={(event) => {
                        console.log(event);
                        console.log(event.target);
                        console.log("now playing");
                        console.log(YouTube.PlayerState);
                        event.target.playVideo();
                        event.target.pauseVideo();
                        emitEvent(event); //emit play to backend here
                    }} // defaults -> noop
                    onPause={(event) => {
                        console.log("now pausing", event);
                        console.log(YouTube.PlayerState.BUFFERING);
                                                //emit pause to backend here
                    }
                    
                />
```

I want to be able to access the event related to this JSX component, so that I may call event.target.playVideo();

I'm listening to sockets in my useEffect() function and I want to call event.target.playVideo() in there depending on the socket msg I recieve.

my UseEffect function to listen to socket:(socket.io client)

```
useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("user-played", (data) => {
            console.log("other user clicked play: ");

            //call event.target.playVideo() here
        });
    }, [socket]);
```

Ideally the workflow would my client here emits("play-video"). Then my backend registers that and emits that event back to client side. Then my client side would recieve("user-played") event and play the video with the play video function above.

Unfortunately I can't just call that anywhere since i need access to the relevant event variable from my YouTube component, so I'm not sure the solution.

I've heard useRef() might work but I was having some trouble with it..although I might just be using it wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with useRef.
To simulate your socket handler, I have added button which when clicked an event is fired and video can be played.

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import YouTube from "react-youtube";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const playerRef = useRef();

  const userPlayed = () => {
    playerRef.current.getInternalPlayer().playVideo();
    // you can also do this with internalPlayer object
    // playerRef.current.internalPlayer.playVideo(); 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <button style={{marginBottom: 20}} onClick={userPlayed}>User Play</button>

      <YouTube
        ref={playerRef}
        videoId={"di0MtYgeJNE"}
        onPlay={(event) => {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(event.target);
            console.log("now playing");
            console.log(YouTube.PlayerState);
            event.target.playVideo();
        }}
        onPause={(event) => {
            console.log("now pausing", event);
            console.log(YouTube.PlayerState.BUFFERING);
        }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```